# Печать и обновление графика в реальном времени OxyPlot - Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oxyplot

Пишу академическую программу - монитор частоты. Для печати графиков использую Nuget Oxylot. Не могу понять как мне напечатать график в реальном времени. Например изменения раз в секунду. По оси X должно быть время, по оси Y - значение double, изменяющееся от 0 до 50.00 единиц (частота в Гц). Взял семпл из документации, а как туда значение вставить и обновлять по времени не понимаю...
Вот класс графика:

```
 public class Plotter
{
    private PlotModel model;
    private DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
    private DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

    private readonly List<OxyColor> colors = new List<OxyColor>
                                        {
                                            OxyColors.Green,
                                            OxyColors.IndianRed,
                                            OxyColors.Coral,
                                            OxyColors.Chartreuse,
                                            OxyColors.Azure
                                        };

    private readonly List<MarkerType> markerTypes = new List<MarkerType>
                                               {
                                                   MarkerType.Plus,
                                                   MarkerType.Star,
                                                   MarkerType.Diamond,
                                                   MarkerType.Triangle,
                                                   MarkerType.Cross
                                               };



    public Plotter()
    {
        model = new PlotModel { Title = "DateTimeAxis" };
    }


    public PlotModel PrintChart()
    {
        var minValue = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(startDate);
        var maxValue = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(endDate);
        model.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = minValue, Maximum = maxValue, StringFormat = "HH:mm" });
        return model;
    }}
```

В основном окошке:

```
public void PrintChart()
    {
        Plotter pt = new Plotter();
        frGraph.Model = pt.PrintChart();
    }
```

По событию кнопки разрешаю печать:

```
private void startDrawing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       PrintChart();
    }
```

И по таймеру пытаюсь обновлять (не уверен, что делаю правильно..)

```
 private void InitializeTimerForChart()
    {
        tickCount.Interval = References.TIMER_INTERVAL; // (1000 мс)
        this.tickCount.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tickCount_Tick);
        tickCount.Enabled = true;
    }
private void tickCount_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                frGraph.Invalidate();//PrintChart();
            });
        }
    }
```

На данный момент класс просто показывает на форме модель с осями, на оси Y текущее время.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что если в `tickCount_Tick` просто вставить `PrintChart` без всяких `Invoke` (стандартный таймер работает в UI потоке)?

Comment: Сейчас пока даже дело не в таймере, можно и убрать диспетчирезацию. Вопрос стоит в том, как график напечатать и обновлять.

Answer (score 2):

В общем получилось создать линейный график без обновлений. Обновлять буду также через таймер раз в секунду.

```
 public PlotModel PrintChart()
    {
        var minValue = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(startDate);
        var maxValue = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(endDate);
        model.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = minValue, Maximum = maxValue, StringFormat = "HH:mm" });
        var leftAxisY = new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left };
        model.Axes.Add(leftAxisY);

        var lineSeries = new LineSeries
        {
            Title = "Линейный график",
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            LineStyle = LineStyle.Automatic,
            MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
            MarkerSize = 5,
            MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
            MarkerFill = OxyColors.Automatic,
            MarkerStrokeThickness = 1.5,
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
           lineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(minValue, i));
        }


        model.Series.Add(lineSeries);
        return model;
   }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу, может кому-то понадобится.

Когда добавляете серию в график, используйте свойство `series.ItemSource`

```
    private void AddSeries(string Name, OxyColor Color, string AxisKey, 
                                                            List<DataPoint> Buffer)
    {
        var series = new LineSeries();
        series.Title = Name;
        series.Color = Color;
        series.YAxisKey = AxisKey;
        series.ItemsSource = Buffer;
        Model.Series.Add(series);
    }
```

`Buffer` здесь это коллекция данных, в который вы будете складывать собираемые точки.
Обновлять следующим образом:

```
  Buffer.Add(new DataPoint(x, y)); // здесь можете делать с коллекцией что 
                                   // хотите: удалять, добавлять, очищать
  Model.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

Да, тип таймера имеет значение: `Threading.Timer` каждый обратный вызов запускает в новом потоке, `DispatcherTimer` в потоке диспетчера (для простых задач наиболее удобен, косяков меньше)

Comment: Спасибо, забрал.